# How do I get Ethminer to work again?

Tags: ethminer, windows, dag

**THE PROBLEM I AM TRYING TO RESOLVE**: ethminer.exe stops working when I execute the bat file below. It initially worked fine for about two weeks and then it stopped working. I have no idea why.

I have an RX480 GPU running on a 64 bit Windows 10 system. And I use Nanopool

I get a message from Windows that ethminer.exe has stopped working and then shuts it down.

Here is (below) what is displayed on the CMD Line. The bat file stops at the CMD output of "miner 10:51:32.581|main Grabbing DAG for #3868abc5ÔÇª"
You can see that the last three characters are corrupt (but the string shows the 
beginning of the actual DAG file name "#3868abc5")

> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Eth\Miner>setx GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR 0
>
> SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
>
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Eth\Miner>setx GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE 100
>
> SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
>
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Eth\Miner>setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
>
> SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
>
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Eth\Miner>setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
>
> SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
>
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Eth\Miner>setx GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
>
> SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
>
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Eth\Miner>cd /
>
> C:>cd "Program files"
>
> C:\Program Files>cd "cpp-ethereum"
>
> C:\Program Files\cpp-ethereum>ethminer.exe -G --cl-extragpu-mem 0
>   --no-precompute -M --opencl-device 1 --opencl-platform 1 -F http://eth-asia1.nanopool.org:8888//worker1/piaras.me@gmail.com Found
>   suitable OpenCL device [Ellesmere] with 8589934592 bytes of GPU memory
>   miner 10:51:31.832|main Getting work package... miner
>   10:51:32.581|main Grabbing DAG for #3868abc5ÔÇª

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR:**

- I used "--cl-extragpu-mem 0 --no-precompute" (gained from the Internet help searches)
- I updated the RX480 drivers and reloaded cpp ethereum (via the 
  wizzard)
- I started with deleting the DAG files from Ethash - when I re-ran 
  the above bat file it started to build a new DAG file. When it finished, Windows simply shut it down again (with same Windows message).  Now when I subsequently delete the DAG file(s), before I execute the bat 
  file, it no longer attempts to build a DAG file (it just hangs as above)

None of these strategies made any difference

**SOME QUESTIONS THAT COULD PERHAPS HELP ME SOLVE THIS PROBLEM:**

- Where would I look for a possible error code? Somewhere in Mist or the 
  Wallet itself perhaps?  I use Mist as my wallet.
- Does Nanopool collect error data?
- Does cpp ethereum itself have an error 
  register (in this instance Windows does not offer an error code that I am aware 
  of?).

Thank you to Nicolas Massart, Badr Bellaj, and 5chdn for offering feedback to my original question. I have included additional information to make the problem clearer. Please let me know if there is any other information that would help in assisting me.

Kind Regards

Piaras

Comment: Hi. Thanks for requesting an answer from me and other better qualified people thanks me. This site is managed by community, so you can't request answers from specific people. Also, if you posted this question and it was put on hold, there's no use to create it again. Simply modify your initial question and we will evaluate if it should be reopened. So I will  vote for closing this question and I highly impel you to go back to the original post and edit it. Thanks.

Comment: OK - I can't find the original post? Can you assist with this? Or maybe peruse the above content and refer me to a site that specifically deals with this kind of issue (I am close to abandoning the whole idea of eth mining).

Comment: I'm sorry, I never tried to mine with windows, but I not sure the dag name corrupted chars are saying anything about your problem, this could simply be a display problem, windows shell is not known to be the best one, especialy for special characters...

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this matter Nicolas - I have taken a second look at one of the Q&A's namely at : 

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18615/issue-grabbing-dag-for-ethminer-but-not-for-expanse

Although the hardware is different to mine the resulting software issue is very similar:

miner  15:47:47|main  Getting work package...
miner  15:47:47|main  Grabbing DAG for #129656acΓÇª

You will notice that the last characters of the DAG file name are corrupted - perhaps this is worthy of attention (it does not appear to have been resolved)

Comment: Following on from the same Q&A at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18615/issue-grabbing-dag-for-ethminer-but-not-for-expanse

"... The OS thought the Miner was a Virus and blocked it, something wrong with the compilation of the Library .dll (and copying one from elsewhere worked), to change your Mining Software"

There is no indication from Norton 360 that ethminer.exe has been blocked (unless there is something I am missing?) - no error message regarding dll and I have reloaded the Mist software - any assistance from the 'been there and done that' would be much appreciated?

Comment: It seems that people having this problem switched to Claymore miner and fixed it.

Comment: OK - thanks to those for the attention to edit and improve the question posed and content on this matter.

Yes I will try the Claymore miner - although it does seem a defeatist path given that others with a similar problem will have no choice but to abandoned ethminer?

Comment: for Windows users perhaps, but this is probably not the majority of miners.

Comment: Good night, I have the same problem, did you manage to solve PIARAS or did you migrate to Claymore? Thank you!!!

Comment: To address the issue where one copy of the DLL works, but another doesn't. This is likely because it was downloaded, but not "unblocked" before unzipping the folder. Windows protects itself by blocking assemblies (and other executables) that were downloaded from the internet but not signed. FIX: Before unzipping, right click on ZIP folder, select "Properties" and then click "Unblock". Now you can unzip and use the assemblies successfully.