# Issue "grabbing DAG" for ethminer (but not for expanse)

Tags: mining, mining-pools, ethminer, dag, expanse

I installed Geth, and successfully synced the blockchain.  However, regardless of whether I use Ethminer, Ethminer with Stratum Proxy, or qtMiner; I always get the same error.  It doesn't *really* throw an error; the mining application just crashes.  For ethminer, the command I used is:

`ethminer -U -F http://eth-eu.dwarfpool.com:80/0xc780f6a9de1cca4e3e5bb25e9dfe0ee52d6d87a6` ([source](https://steemit.com/ethereum/@gobbahfett/easiest-guide-to-mining-ethereum-eth-windows-amd-nvidia-part-1))

The output I get is:

```
Forked from github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum
CUDA kernel ported from Tim Hughes' OpenCL kernel
With contributions from RoBiK, tpruvot and sp_

Please consider a donation to:
ETH: 0xeb9310b185455f863f526dab3d245809f6854b4d

Using grid size 8192, block size 128

Found suitable CUDA device [GeForce GTX 980 Ti] with 6442450944 bytes of GPU memory
miner  15:47:47|main  Getting work package...
miner  15:47:47|main  Grabbing DAG for #129656acΓÇª
```

When I use ethminer with Stratum Proxy, I get this line of output while ethminer is running:

```
2017-06-22 16:48:19,914 INFO proxy # Hashrate for 2130706433 is 0.0 MHs
```

Here's the troubleshooting I've tried so far:

- Using different miners (qtminer, ethminer, etc.)
- Using different mining pools (dwarfpool, ethermine, etc.)
- Clearing the blockchain and resyncing more times than I
  can count

I am attempting to mine on my Windows 10 machine with a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti card.  At this point, I've spent several days reading/trying everything I can.  I suspect there's something dumb that I overlooked.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

____________**UPDATE:**____________

Two observations:

1. If I switch ethminer to mine Expanse (change `eth-eu.dwarfpool.com:80` to `exp-eu.dwarfpool.com:81`), then everything works perfectly.
2. I tried claymore miner, and it works.  However, it was much slower than mining EXP with ethminer; so I would prefer to figure out how to get ethminer mining ETH properly.

Comment: Someone makes the same complaint here: https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/comments/6h5ywm/every_miner_i_use_crashes_while_grabbing_dag_used/ - many Solutions proposed, a few different ones apparently worked. It came down to one of: The OS thought the Miner was a Virus and blocked it, something wrong with the compilation of the Library .dll (and copying one from elsewhere worked), to change your Mining Software. -- Figure out if one of those Solutions is applicable to you and if needed please refine your question, then write your own answer to your question. Thanks.

Comment: So here's a fun fact: if I change the command to use `exp-eu.dwarfpool.com:81` instead of `eth-eu.dwarfpool.com:80` to mine Expanse, ethminer works perfectly.  So why can I grab DAG for EXP but not for ETH?